# How to make minimal data entered into jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Below is a photo of the button to save data, so when I fill it in and it must be filled with 16 characters, if it is not filled with 16 characters, a notification will appear that the characters are less than 16, because the data required by the database is 16 characters. I'm very confused about this because I just found a way to limit the characters

button to enter data:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R8Ei.png]

Comment: Don't post an image of your code. Post the actual code with the question and make sure the code is formatted. I'm not understanding your question. If you want to make sure the text field has 16 character you just invoke `getText().getLength()` to validate the length. So its a simple if condition. Also when using SQL you should use a `PreparedStatement`. Search  this site or read the API for more information.

Comment: From the [image of] code in your question, it looks like you have four `JTextField`s including `nik`, `nama`, `alamat` and `pengunna`. Do each of them have to have 16 characters? Is that exactly 16 characters or at least 16 characters? Can you [edit] your question and post an example valid value? By the way, I recommend displaying the stack trace of the exception in the `catch` block, something like `exc.printStackTrace()`. It will help you find the cause of the exception.